# chrome devtool performance waterfall difference between Chrome and Chromium?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I'm trying to see the call stack of a piece of code, in Chrome and Chromium, they showed different results. I have already disabled all extensions in my Chrome, In the Chrome, can't see those functions call stack, it only shows"Compile Code", Is this a bug or something?

chrome:(can't see the entire function call stack, only show "Compile Code" or "Evaluate Code")
[image]

chromium:(you can see the full detail of the function call stack)

[image]

they are the same hello world code:(/react-17.0.2/fixtures/packaging/babel-standalone/dev.html)

Comment: Looks like source maps are disabled in devtools settings.

Comment: @wOxxOm how to enable this?

Comment: @user956609 did you resolve it? Been stuck at this point as well

Comment: @MAK didn't resolve this